# MacOS Catalina Adobe Premiere Operation Not Permitted

Tags: macos, adobe, photoshop

I have a problem with my Adobe Premiere CC 2019 with MacOS Catalina.

the screenshot is below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqDF9.jpg)

I have give Full Disk Access for Terminal & Finder, but yet still occured the same problem!
Is there anyone can help me with this problem?
I've beeen stuck here for 5 hours without any solution :(

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is not the right forum for this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. Maybe either https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ or https://apple.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to install with sudo permissions yet?

If you haven't or aren't familiar with it, then [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qw_tOUvA4A) a guide on how to set that up.